# Interval Timing Indicators

Tags: workout

I am looking for a way to get some indicator that X time has passed and have it keep repeating.  For example, maybe an iPhone app that plays a particular sounds every X seconds where X can be configured.  Maybe even a watch that I can configure so that every X seconds it vibrates (would not want it to make a sound since I will be using this is a gym) where X can be configured.

I want something like this because I am trying to build my own workout routines where I will do one thing for 1 minute, then another thing for another minute, then another thing for another minute, then rest for 30 seconds, and then repeat with different things.

One things to note is that if there a an iPhone app suggestion, I would want it to work with playing music.

Comment: I have been looking for the same thing! I have a tabata timer, but would like it to have options for different time intervals than 20s/10s. We do a lot of IFAM workouts...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.secondsapp.com/
[image]
There's many iPhone timers out there - here's one I would recommend.  You can assign specific playlist and have it ring or vibrate.  An alternative is GymBoss
[image]
The nice thing about Gymboss is that it's cheap, does not interfere with any music player, you can attach it to your pants/shirt for ease of hearing/vibrating round and you don't have to worry about dropping it.

Comment: Since you don't actually give the name of the iphone app here your answer, I think I found it, being Seconds Pro, that that is exactly what I was looking for, thanks

Comment: Sorry - just added the link - I thought I did have it there.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

[Runtastic Pro](http://blog.runtastic.com/en/runtastic-all-about/intervall-training-implemented-runtastic-iphone-17/) offers an **Interval Training** feature that appears to offer more or less what you require.